# REST API: Using content type vs custom param or endpoint

Tags: api, rest, resources

I'm designing a list endpoint for a resource that merits both full and light version of the resource called /transactions. By default, the response will include the complete resource, but there is also a need to provide clients with the "simplified" version of the resource list.

The first option is to use a custom param (e.g. /transactions?summary=true)
The second option is to use a custom endpoint, though not very RESTful (e.g. /transactions/summary)

The third option is to use content-type to allow a client to declare the alternative response body format. How would this look? (application/json+summary)? Are there any good examples of this being done?

Any other options come to mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third option of using the Accept/Content-Type headers allows the media types to be a representation of a data, separate from the data itself.

A good example of this is github's API: https://developer.github.com/v3/media/

Which uses the http headers to allow clients to choose the format of the data, as well as the version. So in your case, the request could look something like:

`curl http://api.host.com/transactions -H "Accept: application/summary+json"`

And the response would contain a body of your simplified data format and the Content-Type header set to `application/summary+json`

If you want to be more pedantic about it, you could also use a vendor media type as `application/vnd.yourcompany.summary+json`. In this case, `vnd` implies that the media type is a [vendor](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6838#section-3.2) typically associated with application specific media types.

More Info:

- [Collection+JSON](http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/format/)
- [A similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14835790/557525)
- [A bit from restful API design](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#representations)