# REST JSON API optional parameters design

Tags: json, rest, jackson

Our goal is to develop API where you can POST `/data/save/` that will accept some JSON data like below. The main requirement that JSON should contain one of the following attributes:
"attribute1", "attribute2", "attribute3". Namely when one attribute is exist another one should not exist.

```
{
   "name": "test name",
   "attribute1": [
       "test1", "test2"
    ]
    or
    "attribute2": [
        "test3", "test4"
     ]
     or
     "attribute3": true
}
```

The question is how to correctly design such API that it will be easy to use and not confused from the client side.

It would be good to know some best practices in such direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would return a

> 400 Bad Request
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

and a phrase explaining that multiple attributes are not supported.

Comment: Thank you! I guess it would be the best option for our case in order to support optional attributes. Because it would be easier to support one endpoint with validation instead of few endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

I agree such API is confusing for client side.

What's about creating different endpoints:

> POST /data/save/attribute1  json_1
>
> POST /data/save/attribute2  json_2

Answer (score 0):

A [custom media type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685672/how-to-create-a-custom-media-type-application-vnd-for-a-restful-web-service) should clarify how to use your API. It should specify what to include in your request.

Another solution might be, building the request like this:

```
{
   "name": "test name",
   "attr-key": "my-attribute1",
   "values": ["test1", "test2"]
}
```

Comment: introducing mediatypes is discouraged.